# I used to open Chrome browser using selenium ...Getting this below "error"

Tags: selenium

**Jul 13, 2015 1:17:41 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder**

I seen some stackover solutions but those are gave that for firefox browsers...

Here my problem is that error came for "Chrome" browser

Answer (score 0):

Use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM plugin-container.exe");` wherever ur getting this issue.